# MySQL Combine/Group multiple rows into respective groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL and let's say I have a table below

```
Department  | Sale Month | Sale Amount |
----------- | ---------- | ----------- |
Sports      | January    | 500.00      |
Sports      | March      | 200.00      |
Leisure     | February   | 1000.00     |
Consumables | January    | 250.00      |
Consumables | February   | 100.00      |
Consumables | March      | 40.00       |
Clothing    | February   | 50.00       |
Clothing    | March      | 300.00      |
```

I need to compress the above table into a new table that groups each `Department`. I also need to add three new columns for each `Sale Month` and their respective `Sale Amount`

Basically, the final result should like something like this

```
Department  | January    | February    | March    |
----------- | ---------- | ----------- | -------- |
Sports      | 500.00     | -           | 200.00   |
Leisure     | -          | 1000.00     | -        |
Consumables | 250.00     | 100.00      | 40.00    |
Clothing    | -          | 50.00       | 300.00   |
```

What is the necessary function or way to transform the table like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are just getting started, it would be better for you to read the duplicate link to see how to handle this problem in MySQL (or any other database).

Comment: Hi, thanks for letting me know! i will check out the attached link